# What to use instead of STL_PORT on Android NDK 18

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Android NDK revision. Version 18

> gnustl, gabi++, and stlport have been removed.

How to fix it if my project contains 'stl'

Comment: I can fix it with downgrading NDK version to 17. But I think I need to make my project work on newest version.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#runtime_characteristics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use c++_static (which is default with cmake) or c++_shared.